# PreparedStatement

Tags: java

Я недавно начал знакомится с БД, поэтому не судите строго. у меня есть запрос:

```
UPDATE `bedwars` SET `kills` = `kills` + ?, `deaths` = `deaths` + ?, `wins` = `wins` + ?, `bedbreak` = `bedbreak` + ?, `finalkills` = `finalkills` + ? WHERE name=? AND mode="+Mode.getId());
```

Но я не могу точно уверен, что вместо ? будет число больше 0, а выполнять запрос и добавлять 0 не очень хочется. Могу ли я сделать, например так:

```
UPDATE `bedwars` SET `kills` = `kills` + getKills() WHERE name='name' AND mode="+Mode.getId())
```

БЕЗ Потери скорости? (Все это в PreparedStatement)

Comment: Непонятно что вы спрашиваете. Будет ли запрос с меньшм количеством set быстрее?

Comment: Проверять в других местах надо.